# An inequality about the supremum of a bivariate real function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I came across this inequality in Stein's Fourier Analysis. Here's a simplified version:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$. If $S,T \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, then
$$\sup\limits_{S\times T}f(x_1,x_2)\geq \sup\limits_{x_1\in S}\Bigl(\sup\limits_{x_2\in T}f(x_1,x_2)\Bigr)$$

I quite understand that the lhs is greater than or equal to the rhs. For any fixed $x_1\in S$,
$\sup\limits_{S\times T}f(x_1,x_2)\geq \sup\limits_{x_2\in T}f(x_1,x_2)$, which means $\sup\limits_{S\times T}f(x_1,x_2)$ is an upper bound for $\sup\limits_{x_2\in T}f(x_1,x_2)$.

The question is, I couldn't think of a situation where the lhs is strictly larger than the rhs. I think they are always the same but couldn't prove it or think of a counterexample. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): show your attempts to prove it, even if they failed.

Comment: Thanks, the post you pointed out totally answered my question. It is an equality then.